# rails has_and_belongs_to_many different asssocation name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a HABTM relationship between `coupons` and `users`

In my `Coupon` class I have `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` is there a way to name this relationship as `recipients` so I can call `Coupon.recipients` rather than `Coupon.users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :recipients, :class_name => "User"
```